# Counting the number of leaves in a binary tree at a given level

Tags: java, tree, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to count the number of leaves at a certain level (given by depth) but for some reason, I don't understand why it won't work.
Does someone have a better suggestion?
Please have a look below at my code:

```
public static int countLevel(TreeNode root, int depth) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return countLevel(root.left, depth - 1) + countLevel(root.right, depth - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `depth` for?

Comment: In second condiciton you have  AND `&&` should not be OR `||`

Comment: @Boken Actually, I think that's right. That if determines if it's a leaf, and so it returns 1.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem I recommend you renaming `root` in `node`.

Comment: You don't have a return condition for depth < 0. Also, you don't need the 'else' clauses because you return on true.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this

Here `desireDepth` is certain depth you want count the number of leaves and `depth` is current depth.

```
    public static int countLevel(TreeNode root, int desireDepth ,int depth) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (root.left == null && root.right == null && depth == desireDepth) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return countLevel(root.left, desireDepth, depth + 1) + countLevel(root.right, desireDepth, depth + 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm does not give a correct answer because once your depth becomes negative it is not stopping at that particular depth and still going further and counting the leaf nodes, you must give an extra condition of when depth becomes negative (return 0)

Modified version of your solution:

```
public static int countLevel(TreeNode root, int depth) {
    /* optimization
    if(depth<0)
        return 0;
    */
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (root.left == null && root.right == null && depth==0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return countLevel(root.left, depth - 1) + countLevel(root.right, depth - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to return 0 at negative depths, but it's a nice optimization. The key part is the `&& depth == 0` bit which ensures leaves that aren't at the correct depth are omitted.

Comment: @ggorlen - Oh yes! thank you.